# Can you use a MacBook without the battery?

Tags: macbook, battery

Can I use my MacBook (13 inch aluminum late '08) without the battery and only plugged in?

Comment: Why would you want that? I have a MacBook without bettery now (battery got wet and refuses to work). It works, but it's really annoying. I can't just put it to sleep when carrying it around, I need to be very *very* careful with MagSafe, as it comes out too easy...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bear in mind that the battery might need the trickle charge to keep itself in top condition. Taking the battery out will see it gradually drain and there might be an issue with its charge when you plug it back in again.

Also, having the battery in means you've effectively got a UPS built-in. You can keep going if there's a power cut or someone trips over your power cord.

Comment: I will be keeping it in most of the time and only out for a few hours at a time.  Will this improve or worsen the battery life?

Comment: @Mr. Man - that I couldn't say for definite, I don't think it will reduce the battery life but it probably won't significantly increase it either given that laptops are designed to be used with the battery left in all the time.

Comment: @Mr. Man It probably won't make much of a difference, though that depends largely upon how you are already using the battery. For optimal battery life, you should not charge it while warm (Don't use the laptop if the battery is also charging, just leave it off and let the battery charge) and don't heat the battery up (so don't leave it in your car in the sun); The safety circuits will take care of the rest.

Comment: Alright, I think I will just leave it in, thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should not be an issue assuming you don't trip on the cord :)

Answer (score 1):

Most laptops you can - Have you tried removing the battery, plugging it in, and testing? It certainly won't damage the laptop.

Comment: No, I haven't tried, that's why I asked here :P.

Comment: @MrMan: Well, if you do try, you can answer your own question :)

Answer (score 1):

though the battety is expensives, but compare to the laptop, the battery is much cheaper. Without batteris is bad for the laptop when unexpected power outages.